# react-native integration with existing native project getting error Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate latest RN project into native project. Both project are in separate directories that means my native project does not exist in predefined ios folder.

versions:

RN Native: 0.63.3
@react-native-community/cli: 4.13.0 installed globally using yarn global add @react-native-community/cli.

I am getting error stating react-native-community package not found.

My pod file is mentioned below:

```
require_relative '../AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!


def main_pods
    config = use_native_modules!
    use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
end


target 'NativeFramework' do
    main_pods
end

target 'Example' do
    main_pods
end
```

Error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] /usr/local/bin/node -e try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'
```

Comment: did u follow https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps ?

Comment: I did but documentation seems to be outdated. Pod file does not match with upgrade tool for 0.63.3 as mentioned here: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.63.3

Comment: @AnilSharma did u manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You say you've installed `@react-native-community/cli` with Yarn. The error message indicates that may not be working for you. It's not surprising, because your Podfile says it can be found in a subdirectory of your project.

Why not install with `npm` and see what happens?

1. `cd` to AwesomeProject
2. `npm i @react-native-community/cli`

Alternatively, change your Podfile so it refers to the global location.

Answer (score -1):

For some weird reason it worked with yarn install and then doing the pod install

Answer (score -1):

#### After so much times passed, I found the problem is that the android-project dir must be in the react-native-project dir !

> react-native": "0.68.2" java11 Apple M1 Pro

---

### Integration ReactNative with Existing Apps

> https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

### Problems

- Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'

  > After so much times passed, I found the problem is that the android-project dir must be in the react-native-project dir !

  - [Error: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object in react-native for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952564/error-unable-to-determine-the-current-character-it-is-not-a-string-number-ar)

    - removing @react-native-community and run npx react-native run-android and fix errors and reAdd @react-native-community
  - [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

    - brew install node
    - brew install watchman
    - use java11
  - No need install @react-native-community/cli
  - Terminal Warning -> 'To install do: 'rvm install "ruby

    ```bash
    rvm reset
    rvm install 2.7.2
    rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
    ```
  - Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories

    > delete dependencyResolutionManagement in  settings.gradle, add to allprojects.repositories to root build.gradle
  - Error:Unable to start the daemon process.

    - [mac too many open files in system](https://blog.abreto.net/archives/2020/02/macos-too-many-open-files.html)
  - Others

    ```bash
    # try
    sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
    open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
    ```